# How to submit data to modify feature using applyEdits of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, features

I'm new to ArcGIS API. In a form, how can you submit data to modify a feature using applyEdits? No map is involved with this.

I have a form that populates the editable data with javascript. When the user clicks save changes, I want the changes to be processed using applyEdits.

So far, I have:

```
var Editable = new FeatureLayer("......", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT
    });

    Editable.applyEdits(null,[ {
      "attributes": {
        "bldg_prop_id": 6086,
        "bldg_water_utility_name": "New Data"
      }
    }],null);
```

This doesn't work but I'm not sure where to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Late response, but should it not be an Array of Graphic objects and it might be wise to add callback and errback functions even if they are optional, to get information on the error that occurs. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#applyedits